# Hide Autogenerated Column in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that uses autogenerated columns, because the user can select the columns to return in a query.  I want to hide the column with the identity.  How do I hide the autogenerated column?  Even in the databound event the columns count is zero.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I discovered how to do this.  You need to use the rowdatabound event and hide the cell when the row is bound.

```
Protected Sub ResultGrid_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles ResultGrid.RowDataBound
        e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: +1, Only thing to watch for is that you change it for appropriate RowTypes. For example if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Pager) { e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false; }

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have hacked around the issue with the following.  I have written helper functions to give me the correct column index and then to hide the column desired. Once the helper functions are in place, you simply call the one liner from the gridview_databound function.

```
protected void grd_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        HideAutoGeneratedGridViewColumn(grd, "nContractID");           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

    public int getColumnIndex(GridView grd, string sColumnName)
{
    return getColumnIndex(grd, sColumnName, false);
}
/// <summary>
/// Returns the columns index of the specified column based on the header text.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="grd"></param>
/// <param name="sColumnName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int getColumnIndex(GridView grd, string sColumnName, bool bAutoGeneratedColumn)
{
    int ReturnVal = -1;
    try
    {
        if (grd != null)
        {
            if (!bAutoGeneratedColumn)
            {
                #region Static Columns
                if (grd.Columns.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < grd.Columns.Count; x++)
                    {
                        if (grd.Columns[x] != null)
                        {
                            if (grd.Columns[x].HeaderText.ToLower() == sColumnName.ToLower())
                            {
                                ReturnVal = x;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                #region AutoGenerated Columns
                if (grd.HeaderRow != null)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < grd.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; x++)
                    {
                        if (grd.HeaderRow.Cells[x] != null)
                        {
                            if (grd.HeaderRow.Cells[x].Text.ToLower() == sColumnName.ToLower())
                            {
                                ReturnVal = x;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ReturnVal = - 1;
        LogMessage("getColumnIndex(GridView grd, string sColumnName, bool bAutoGeneratedColumn) Error", ex.Message);
    }
    return ReturnVal;
}   
/// <summary>
/// Returns the columns index of the specified column based on the header text.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sColumnName"></param>
/// <param name="r"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public int getColumnIndex(string sColumnName, GridViewRow r)
{
    int ReturnVal = -1;
    try
    {
        if (r != null)
        {
            if (r.Cells.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < r.Cells.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (r.Cells[x] != null)
                    {
                        if (((System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell)(r.Cells[x])).ContainingField.HeaderText == sColumnName)
                        {
                            ReturnVal = x;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ReturnVal = -1;
    }
    return ReturnVal;
}
public void HideAutoGeneratedGridViewColumn(GridView grd, string sColumnName)
{
    HideAutoGeneratedGridViewColumn(grd, getColumnIndex(grd, sColumnName, true));
}
public void HideAutoGeneratedGridViewColumn(GridView grd, int nColumnIndex)
{
    try
    {
        grd.HeaderRow.Cells[nColumnIndex].Visible = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < grd.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            grd.Rows[x].Cells[nColumnIndex].Visible = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogMessage("HideAutoGeneratedGridViewColumn(GridView grd, int nColumnIndex) Error", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the column was greater than zero, if so then I'd use the fact that the column collection can be referenced by column name as well as integer to set the identity column to hidden.

Comment: Auto generated columns are not included in the column collection.

Comment: Do it in the DataBound event at which point I'm pretty sure the autogenerated columns will be in the columns collection.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it? The simplest thing would be to not include it in the select query.

If you need it and know the column position:

```
gridView.Columns[KnownColumnIndex].Visible = false;
```

Comment: I need the index to include as the datakey for selecting the row.

Comment: this did not work for me, gridView.Columns.Count is zero for Autogenerated columns.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the autogenerated column header and cell without it looking messed up like the databound will do.  This is the correct answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680832/hide-column-of-an-autogenerated-gridview-with-one-templatefield)

```js
Protected Sub Gdvisitor_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gdvisitor.RowCreated
    If (e.Row.Cells.Count > 1) Then
        e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```