# Hide column of an autogenerated gridview with one templatefield

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have autogenerated columns here from visitid and so on. The first column however was a templatefield. now I wanted to hide VisitID. I tried this code but it didn't work. I am using vb as my codebehind

```
e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = False
```

[image]

Comment: In which event handler are you using this line: `e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = False`?

Comment: I tried it on rowcreated and rowdatabound it says  
"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried several ways but also ended with this code and it worked finally I just added a condition. I'm sorry maybe I lacked information. I had a pagination in the gridview.. Here was my working code.

```
Protected Sub Gdvisitor_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gdvisitor.RowCreated
    If (e.Row.Cells.Count > 1) Then
        e.Row.Cells(1).Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

At first it was "....cells.count < 0" and that didn't work the index was still out of range but when I changed it to 1. It worked. I think the pagination has something to do with it. I'm not sure though... Thank you for all the help

Comment: Wow Thanks!!!!!! This seemed like a simple problem when I was starting but it took way to long to find an answer. Thanks again Ley47!

Answer (score 2):

To hide the columns you need to set visible to false for column not the cell.

```
gridView1.Columns(1).Visible = False
```

Comment: I tried this and this is how I did it and put it after databind but it said "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

I'm not good with this did I put it on the wrong place?

Comment: You have to put it after bind grid, like gridView.DataSource = dt; gridView1.DataBind(); gridView1.Columns(1).Visible = False

Comment: hmm thats how I did it like this:  Gdvisitor.DataSource = dt;
        Gdvisitor.DataBind();
        Gdvisitor.Columns(1).Visible = False....... But I got that error I tried replacing 1 with 0 and it hid the view visitor column but to the next indexes it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Check the data source how many columns you getting in data source?

Comment: In the datasource columns are 6.

Comment: Check you might be using the index on some other place that would have been removed after hiding the column. For example you would be accessing index 5 for 6th column before hiding and after hiding you need to use index 4 instead of 5 as now you have 5 columns instead of 6.

Comment: Hm. I think that doesn't happen? cause it has 6 indexes and I'm hiding index 1 and also accessing index 1.. So if ever a column is hidden there will still be an index 1 right? and I also tried the breakpoint thing. It wasn't able to hide the column saying "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"   PLEASE CORRECT ME IF I'M WRONG

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```
 GridView.Columns(1).Visible = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
       gridview name.columns(column number).visible=false;
```

If u want to hide the 3rd column use the above code as:

```
        gridview name.columns(3).visible=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Autogeneraterd grids' columns cannot be hidden. If you do a check like `dg.columns.count` you'll get `0` instead of `6`.

Use a template column for each one or do this using jQuery.